# cakephp: database, xml or json to generate report

Tags: xml, database, json, cakephp, report

I'm trying to generate a student's report card. What is the best way to store the stages of development of each child and his grades? For example:

Name:Carla Smith
Class: Prep II

MOTOR DEVELOPMENT                               TERM1           TERM2
Draws freehand pictures                         B                A      
Cuts and pastes pictures                        A                A      
......

WORK HABITS
Works independently                             C                A       
Follows instructions                            C                B

TERM 1: Teacher's comments

TERM 2: Teacher's comments

Is it better to store these data in the database or shall I store them in XML or JSON files or are there any other tecniques that i'm not aware of? I don't think it is possible to store in database coz' each development category is going to have many sub categories ie. Motor Development category itself is divided into sub categories.

Any help is much appreciated.

As for the report I intend to use tcpdf from the net.

Comment: Did you consider something like MongoDB?

Comment: I will checkout MongoDB and let u know. By the way, is it possible to use MYSQL for the rest of the website and MongoDB for the report? coz' i'm already usng MYSQL now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can use both databases in an application.

Comment: I just tried out MongoDB from MongoDB.org. Will i be able to store the above data: developement categories, subcategories, student's grades for term 1 and term 2, and teacher's comments for term 1 and term 2 into MongoDB? thanks.

Comment: Since there will be many students, i have to generate a report card for each student. Certainly there will be a lot of data to store in the database. These data are in the format of JSon or XML. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is semi-structured (subcategories...), so XML and JSON seem to be adequate formats.

I think both directions you mention make sense: using a database layer (there are databases that support XML data, for example eXist-db, Sedna, Sausalito, MarkLogic...) or a file system layer (with an XML or JSON file that an XQuery/XSLT engine such as Saxon, Zorba, ... can read and update).

As a rule of thumb, if you have little data, using a file might be easier and faster to set up, whereas if you have a lot of data, an XML database can bring a lot of added value and better performance (indices for example).

Comment: Since there will be many students, i will have to generate a report card for each student. Certainly there will be a lot of data. I'm already using MYSQL for the rest of the website. Is it possible to use a different database (for XML data) for the report alone? I've never created an application or website that uses 2 databases. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, i'm using cakePHP for the website development.

Comment: hi xqib-team, i visited eXist-db, Sedna and MarkLogic websites. I'm using Cakephp with WAMP for the website. I'm a beginner with XML databases, so can u please recommend which one will be the easiest to learn? thank you.

Comment: I guess I will choose between eXist and Sedna coz' both of them are open source. Which one has better developer support like forums, etc...?

Comment: Hi, I am not very familiar with them and the support they offer, but technically I think Sedna provides a PHP API, and eXist should also be compatible with PHP using REST or XML-RPC. MongoDB also has a PHP driver. This might allow you to use any of them in addition to MYSQL in your PHP code.